# Collating 2 dimensional array into array of objects with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

For the life of me I cannot figure this out.

I need to take a 2 dimensional array and create an array of objects with a specified keyname in another array.  How would I go about doing this?

I'm trying return an object like this:

**needed result:**

```
[
  {
    map: 'map-1',
    user: 'user-1',
    type: 'type-1',
    name: 'name-1',
    street: 'street-1' ,
    city: 'city-1'
  },
  {
    map: 'map-2',
    user: 'user-2',
    type: 'type-2',
    name: 'name-2',
    street: 'street-2' ,
    city: 'city-2'
  }
  ...
]
```

**Current code:**

```
var collection = [
  ['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'],
  ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'],
  ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'],
  ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'],
  ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'],
  ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']
];
var keys = [
  "map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", 'city'
]
const arrayColumn = (arr, n) => arr.map((x, i) => {
  return {[keys[i]]:x[n]}
});

let x = keys.map((x, i)=>{
  return arrayColumn(collection, i)
})
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.unzip()` to transpose the collection to rows, and then map the transposed collection, and combine each row with the keys via `_.zipObject()`:

```js
const collection = [['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'], ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'], ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'], ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'], ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'], ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']];
const keys = ["map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", "city"];

const result = _.unzip(collection).map(o => _.zipObject(keys, o));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea with Lodash/fp - generate a function with `_.flow()`, that uses `_.unzip()` to transpose the collection, and map with `_.zipObject()` to convert each row to an object:

```js
const fn = keys => _.flow(
  _.unzip,
  _.map(_.zipObject(keys)),
)

const collection = [['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'], ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'], ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'], ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'], ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'], ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']];
const keys = ["map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", "city"];

const result = fn(keys)(collection);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce functions are never easy to understand upon first inspection. Look at the `i` & `j`, where they are created and how are they used.

```js
var collection = [
  ['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'],
  ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'],
  ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'],
  ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'],
  ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'],
  ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']
];
var keys = [
  "map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", 'city'
];

// Iterate over lenght of objects in inner array(s)
var result = collection[0].map((_, j) => {
  // For every key, save value in an object under its name with value from collection at position of key index and index of item being created
  return keys.reduce((obj, key, i) => {
    obj[key] = collection[i][j];
    return obj;
  }, {});
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and build new object with the wanted properties.

```js
var collection = [['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'], ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'], ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'], ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'], ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'], ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']],
    keys = ["map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", 'city'],
    result = collection.reduce((r, a, i) => {
        a.forEach((v, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || {})[keys[i]] = v);        
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var collection = [
  ['map-1', 'map-2', 'map-3', 'map-4', 'map-5', 'map-6'],
  ['user-1', 'user-2', 'user-3', 'user-4', 'user-5', 'user-6'],
  ['type-1', 'type-2', 'type-3', 'type-4', 'type-5', 'type-6'],
  ['name-1', 'name-2', 'name-3', 'name-4', 'name-5', 'name-6'],
  ['street-1', 'street-2', 'street-3', 'street-4', 'street-5', 'street-6'],
  ['city-1', 'city-2', 'city-3', 'city-4', 'city-5', 'city-6']
];
var keys = [
  "map", "user", 'type', "name", "street", 'city'
]



const result = Object
  .entries(collection)
  .reduce((acc, [,x], i) => {
    return x.map((y, j) => ({
      ...acc[j],
      [keys[i]]: y
    }))
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```